# Kivy ModalView border

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to add a border-radius to a ModalView in Kivy, but I don't know how to do this without a Image.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        p = ModalView()
        p.add_widget(Label(text="Hello!"))
        p.size_hint = (.2, .2)
        p.background_color = (0, 1, 1, 1)
        #add a border radius here
        p.open()
        return
        
MyApp().run()
```

If someone knows how, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own custom `ModalView` class as:

```
class MyModalView(ModalView):
    pass
```

Then define how the new class looks using `Builder`:

```
        Builder.load_string('''
<-MyModalView>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [20,]
        ''')
```

Starting the `kv` rule with a `-` indicates that the normal `kv` rule for displaying a `ModalView` should not be inherited by the new class.

The just use `MyModalView` rather than `ModalView` in your code.